# ArrayAdapter gets only one value after substring. Without substring it works perfectly

Tags: java, android, substring, android-arrayadapter

Simple gallery activity, i want to send the selected image names.
I have 2 files.

From **Gallery.java** I am sending with Sharedpreferences the image file name to **Upload.java**

```
  FeedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                fd=FeedPref.edit();


                fd.putString("uname", selectImages);
                fd.apply();
                Intent sample2=new Intent(Gallery.this,Upload.class);
                startActivity(sample2);
```

I got the full name with the path.

> (storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20160627_092431.jpg|/storage/emulated/0/Download/eiffel_tower_bg.png
>   )

I just want the "eiffel_tower_bg.png" part.

So on the second file, i receive the file names, and show them into a listview. Easy.

```
FeedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String  uname=FeedPref.getString("uname",null+"\n");


    String[] values = new String[] {uname};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I tried with for cycle to clean the strings to get for example: iffel_tower_bg.png.

When I  click on 2 or more pictures, just the last item gets to the listview.
my code:

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    FeedPref =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String uname = FeedPref.getString("uname", null + "\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < uname.length();i++)
    {
        int pos = uname.lastIndexOf("/");

        String x =uname.substring(pos+1 , uname.length()-1);


        String[] values = new String[] {x};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);



        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

I dont know how to clean and show all the image file names.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: You are putting a single string in the SharedPreferences in case of multiple files ? That could be an issue.

Comment: I know that this loop will run x times(uname lenght), this is just one of the tried solution.. I tried also to  loop thru an array, same result.

Comment: it works without the substring part.

Comment: @Janos Question : Is "|" used as delimiter to seperate image paths??

Answer (score 0):

if i am right you have in selectImages string with image names, so if that is write doing :

```
uname.lastIndexOf("/");
```

will always get last / so

```
uname.substring(pos+1 , uname.length()-1);
```

will get last image path.

So you should split your string to get in Array single image item, i do not know if you have **/asd/image1,/asda/asd/imag2** or different string but in my example you should split by , .

Answer (score -1):

please change code as like below.it will work.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

FeedPref =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
// String uname = FeedPref.getString("uname", null + "\n");
String uname = "storage/emulated/0/Download/eiffel_tower_bg.png|storage/emulated/0/Download/eiffel_tower_bg.png|storage/emulated/0/Download/eiffel_tower_bg.png";
    String[] values= uname.split("\\|");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length;i++)
    {
       // int pos = uname.lastIndexOf("/");
        String x =values[i];
       Log.e("Log","values "+i+"="+values[i]);      
    }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: the app just stopped. this isnt working, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.urmosviktor.photonet/com.example.urmosviktor.photonet.Upload}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Comment: please check value for x ,put log to uname and extract exact data from uname.can you put ,what is content in uname.

Comment: i get nothing from log, because the app is not responding after i click the button. The problem is that i want to loop tru a string length..

Comment: comment from for to setadapter and log your uname after give me that uname content.

Comment: the log data is okay as I said top. these are the file names, without cleaning. it works well, if I click 5 picture, all the picture is sent. but if I clean with substring, just the last item gets displayed.    07-21 12:29:29.842 29529-29529/? I/adat: /storage/emulated/0/Download/2016-07-14-14-49-22--714660760.jpg|/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20160715_083106.jpg|

Comment: as per your log uname contain only one image.

Comment: How can you fetch values[i] from an empty string array ?? Its wrong.

Comment: i was storing data into String array.which extracted from your uname content.

Comment: How can you store data into an empty String array of size 0 ??

Comment: give it to size as 100 or any number .if you don't want to define size then take it as arrayList.

Comment: @Vasant Your answer is wrong. I down voted your answer. Your code is having an exception & it is not useful. So if you edit & correct it, I can remove my down vote. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117906/discussion-between-vasant-and-sjy).

Comment: @sjy, I updated my answer.it will extract all your images.

Answer (score -1):

From your string path, the delimiter being used to separate the multiple images seems to be "|" (Vertical Line). The below code splits the **uname** using that delimiter & stores individual file names to values array. Try

```
String[] array = uname.split("\\|");
String[] values = new String[array.length];
for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int lastIndexOfSlash = array[i].lastIndexOf("/");
    values[i] = array[i].substring(lastIndexOfSlash+1, array[i].length());
}
```